How can I attract users to engage with non-political forum games and communities amidst the overwhelming focus on politics?
I feel like some users are so entrenched in political discussions that they overlook or dismiss non-political content.
Is there a subset of users who intentionally downvote non-political posts as a way to express dissatisfaction with a platform's perceived neutrality?
I get that politics are important I'm not I guess asking for everyone to just dumb themselves down and be stupid idiots. What I'm saying is Ridiculousness and funny silly things always get my mind off of stress and tense anxiety provoking feelings. It's a form of relief for me I would say and I just kind of want to like spread that joy? For lack of better verbage.
And it's so frustrating I have all kinds of different communities that they can participate in.
I have a story Community where you post a sentence and people continue the story in the comments, I have the opposite of Life tips you give horrible life tips instead sitting it up as a positive, I have stupid ask Community where you ask absurd stupid funny questions, obviously I have a memes community, I have a community where you post an idea of something that sounds perfect and indestructible like an unlusable remote and people add all the really horrible details about it, like you can't lose the remote, but it gives off deadly radiation that makes you grow an arm out of your forehead every four seconds or some sort of negative like that and it just keeps going, and a whole bunch of others.
Like I'm going to be real with everyone here reading this, I know I'm not the greatest thing since sliced bread. I know I'm not unique and special and the communities I made are one of a kind I know that.
I'm not foolish to think that I'm the super extra Ultra creative that is wondering why no one participates in my super extra Ultra creative communities that only I could think of. That's not why I'm asking this question it just seems like everyone wants to be angry about politics all the time. It's just really disheartening that's all and I just don't understand it.
I feel like this is also important I'm on Lemmy if you know what that is it's a Federated link aggregator I feel like mentioning this is important because user basis of different social medias tend to be a little different in their mannerisms and what they believe in politically if that makes any difference to their motivations.
How do I get users to engage in more non political content and have fun, rather then only engaging in politics?

I run a geo-located Telegram group for "All things [City]" and it over the years it has become the largest, moderated, spam and scam free community for my city. although the ratio of active vs lurker members is not quite where I'd like it to be (only a small fraction actually participate, but has consistently done so over the last 5 years) I have strive to make it as welcoming and diverse as it can possibly be.
During the last election cycle in my country, things were getting heated up way too much. While active membership rose quite quickly, the tone was getting out of hand, with clearly opposite partisan fields throwing all sorts of insults, epithets and general nastiness each other's way.
My solution was to declare any political discussion as off topic, while creating an alternate, solely politics centered group with a moderator representing each partisan camp, so no one would feel un-represented in the new community's leadership.
I used a Bot's feature to blacklist the most common name-calling, but instead of kicking, muting or banning members who tried to keep the partisan insult-fest going, it would silently delete the message and privately invite the user to the new politics-centric community.
Turns out that insulting your opponents is not as fun absent an audience, and while I did lose some members, the politics-centered group fizzled out after the elections, only the most vocal members actually joined up, and the whole community was grateful that the few loud activist users stopped with their "activism"
It may or may not be a solution for your case, but it worked for me
I do keep detailed historical data on membership and activity on my communities, however the dataset has not yet been anonymized for public consumption. If anyone is interested, I could put it in my to-do list for everyone's benefit to have some actual data shedding light on the effectivity of this approach.
